# Detect when memory address is being written to

Tags: c, emulation

I have an array of bytes that is used as an emulated system RAM. I want to make a bullet-proof patch for a given cell, that detects when it's being written to, and overwrites it instantly. Using a loop like

```
for (;;) {
    address = x;
    sleep(y);
}
```

has a flaw that there's a minimum possible value for sleep, which appears to be nearly identical to the emulated frame length, so it'd only patch the address once per frame. So, if it's written to 100 times per frame by a game, such a patch will make little sense.

I have some hooks on writing, but those only catch writes by reading the game's code being executed, while I want to make such patches work for any memory region, not just RAM, hence I can't rely on interpreting the emulated code too much (it simply doesn't match for all regions I want to patch).

So I need some pragrammatical watchpoint, having a pointer to the array, and a byte I want to watch change.

Comment: If there's not too much other stuff on the same page, guard-pages and/or write-protected pages might help on systems with MMU.

Comment: maybe check wether the performance library of your choice (TAU or PAPI to name two) exposes its hooks on memory access

Comment: What built-in debugger hardware does the processor have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although C is not an object-oriented language, I would use an object-oriented approach here:

1. Wrap the emulated memory up in an opaque pointer that can only be read and written to with a specific set of functions (e.g. `memory_write_byte` and `memory_read_byte`).
2. Make the memory object maintain a list of function pointers that point to callback functions for handling write events.  Whenever a write happens, make it call all those callbacks.
3. The part of the code that wants to monitor that spot in memory can register a callback with the memory object, and whenever the callback gets called it can modify the memory if needed.

Comment: What does this accomplish? Any c function can just not use the wrapper and write to your protected memory.

Comment: +1, cross-platform solution, @Claris, an opaque struct prevents you from read-write (is only accesible through the property get-set methods), take a look to  [Mutator method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#C_example)

Comment: @Claris It depends if you give them a reference or not. I think the suggestion is that you make everything go through a well-defined API.

Comment: Sounds like I'll have to edit the emulated core... Not really an option, if so.

Comment: OK, as an alternative, can't you just edit the memory after each emulated instruction is run?  This assumes that the code is structured well so that there is some loop or function that runs every time an instruction executes, and it assumes that there is no need to modify the memory sooner than that.  What emulator are you working with and in what ways can you edit it?

Comment: The core is in asm, so there's no C-ish function that writes to memory. Gens-rr mod. I can edit it all I want, but I prefer to not touch anything I can avoid touching, so I'm doing all my stuff inside my additional source files.

Comment: Marked as an answer, since it will be partially that way. I'll embed calls to functions that report the write right into the asm code that writes there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look into shared memory ala mmap. Using mmap you can have the same page shared by two processes and one of the processes can be read only.

When a write on this memory region occurs a SIGSEGV would be generated, which you can catch, and then take some sort of an action. This is using UNIX terminology, but you can do the same thing with windows it is just slightly more involved.